# How to understand the pointer when assign value in integer and single character in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I try to change something a little when assigning value and things suddenly get a lot more complicated and result become mysterious. I don't mean to make code dirty, I just want to compare difference to help myself better understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int h = 10;
    int *i = &h;
    int j = &h;
    int *k = h;
    printf("%i;%p\n", h, &h);
    printf("%p;%i;%p\n", i, *i, &i);
    printf("%i;%p;%p\n", j, j, &j);      //how to print out h by j?
    printf("%i;%p\n\n", k, &k);        // how to print out *k?

    char a = 'M';
    char *b = &a;
    char c = &a;
    char *d = a;
    printf("%c;%p\n", a, &a);
    printf("%p;%c;%p\n",b, *b, &b);
    printf("%c;%p;%p\n", c, c, &c);        //how to print out a by c?
    printf("%c;%p\n", d, &d);        //how to print out *d?

    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
10;0xbfcef838
0xbfcef838;10;0xbfcef83c
-1076955080;0xbfcef838;0xbfcef840    //where does -1076955080 come from?
10;0xbfcef844

M;0xbfcef836
0xbfcef836;M;0xbfcef848
6;0x36;0xbfcef837        //where does 6 come from?
M;0xbfcef84c
```

Comment: Read about pointer dereferencing.

Comment: You should not print the *address* of soemthing using `%i` always express addresses in hex.

Comment: `how to print out h by j?` Assuming an `int` can hold an address without loss you can do this: `printf("%d %d\n", h, *((int *)j));`

Comment: @FiddlingBits ((int *)j)  It works, I don't know why but I feel this is exactly the correct way,  tell you the truth I'm still not 100 percent clear about what's going on

Comment: @FiddlingBits Besides I try to use the same scheme on the c, use *((char *)c), but it does not work, can not print out 'M'. don't know why.

Comment: a character cannot hold an address value.   Note that your compiler should be complaining about this code in several different ways.  Do compile with all warnings enabled.  This is a good example of why warnings should be corrected, not ignored

Comment: Just don't do stuff like this. Integers and pointers are not the same thing, and in particular on modern machines `int` can't hold all the information that a pointer needs. If your platform supports this, the types that may hold pointer values are called `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`.

Comment: To answer "where does -1076955080 come from?", try converting that value to base 16 (hexadecimal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't even compile (in ideone as c++, c probably warns)

```
int h = 10;
int j = &h;
```

Is not valid . You mean

```
int h = 10;
int *j = &h;
```

Which says that j is a pointer to an int (`int *j`) and it is initialized to point at h (`= &h`);

To pring h by j

```
printf("%d\n", *j);
```

Think of it this way. `int *j` says that `*j` is an int. So you have to type `*j` when you want the int that j points at

Comment: This no problem, I understand this is supposed to be the standard way, I just curious what will happen if I change something a little and perhaps understand why, I believe it can help me get better understanding of pointer in C also strengthen debug skill

Comment: so whats your question

Comment: I post 6 questions and so for I got 2 answers, the 1st and 5th